# maxZoom not working with Google Maps Markerclusterer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using this [markerclusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/index.html) library, and I'm trying to force the marker clusters to switch to normal markers after a certain zoom level is reached. But nothing happens when it in this case goes past level 6. I tested this by including a zoom event listener that wrote the current zoom level to the browser console.

There are not many code examples on the markerclusterer library, so maybe I'm [doing it wrong](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/GridOptions.html). I also searched on Github for code examples with the markerclusterer and maxZoom, but no luck :S

```
                    render( { count, position }, stats, map ) {

                    // change color if this cluster has more markers than the mean cluster
                    const color = count > Math.max(10, stats.clusters.markers.mean ) ? config.markers.cluster.colorLarge : config.markers.cluster.colorSmall;

                    // create svg literal with fill color
                    const svg = `<svg fill="${color}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 240 240" width="50" height="50">
                        <circle cx="120" cy="120" opacity=".6" r="70" />
                        <circle cx="120" cy="120" opacity=".3" r="90" />
                        <circle cx="120" cy="120" opacity=".2" r="110" />
                        <text x="50%" y="50%" style="fill:#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-size="50" dominant-baseline="middle" font-family="roboto,arial,sans-serif">${count}</text>
                        </svg>`;

                    const title = `Cluster of ${count} markers`,
                        // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
                        zIndex = Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count;

                    const clusterOptions = {
                        position,
                        zIndex,
                        title,
                        icon: {
                            url: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svg)}`,
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point( 25, 25 ),
                        },
                        maxZoom: 6
                    };

                    return new google.maps.Marker( clusterOptions );
                }
```

Any ideas how to fix this?